# Como testar update em props no ReactJS

Tags: javascript, react, jest

Criei um componente `Button` que possui uma função `onClick` e uma prop `disabled`. A função define um state `isLoading` como `true`, e a prop recebe o valor deste state, ou seja, enquanto a página estiver carregando o botão estará desabilitado.

Porém, ao simular o clique, o state e a prop não são atualizados, assim não consigo testar para ver se o botão foi realmente desabilitado.

index.jsx

```
<Button
  onClick={handleClick}
  data-testid="backward-button"
  disabled={this.state.isLoading}
/>
```

index.test.js

```
const wrapper = shallow(<ParentComponent />);
const button = wrapper.find('[data-testid="backward-button"]');

button.simulate('click');
wrapper.instance().forceUpdate();

expect(button.prop('disabled')).toBeTruthy();
```

A dúvida é: como posso verificar o valor da prop `disabled` depois do state ser alterado?

Estou usando o Jest e o Enzyme para os testes.

Comment: Não deu certo esse teste? apresenta algum erro?

Comment: `expect(button.prop('disabled')).toBe(true);` já tentou?

Comment: Ainda nao havia tentado, Obrigado pela ajuda !

Comment: Sim, ele fala que o teste falhou, Desse jeito que vc propos nao funcionou, ele continua dando false

Comment: Não é que falhou é que o estado do componente não foi alterado, então deve algo nesse tipo ... falha nesse caso não é o problema, o problema que você deseja uma alteração de componente que não está ocorrendo. `expect(button.prop('disabled')).toBe(false);` coloque `false` pra ver se passa!